# How can I run a pure java server on AWS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have registered to the free AWS plan, and I wish to run a pure java server code I have written on this machine, so I will be able to take this server's IP and use it to connect with my client.

After some searching in AWS I have found many products and features, but I still don't understand how to perform this simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new EC2 Instance SSH into it, install java and prerequisites.

Ensure -

1. Your Security Group is opened for port 22 for external internet - 0.0.0.0/0 ( or at least your IP )
2. Use t2.micro instance size - only that is covered under the free tier
3. Remember to save / store your keypair safely
4. Check the below links

   - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-launch-instance_linux.html
   - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-connect-to-instance-linux.html
   - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-add-volume-to-instance.html
   - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-clean-up-your-instance.html

Comment: I will do this. Thank you very much!